# User Control Multiple Times on the web page, javascript not working

Tags: javascript, user-controls

User Control Multiple Times on the web page:

I have a user control with a Grid and a list box
Grid is set as auto create column = True
I pass query to the control and populate the grid in Page_Load event
User double clicks the rows on the grid to choose
These rows are added to list the box (Column 1 as value and Column 2 as Dispaly)
If user double clicks the row on list box - it is removed from the selection
Plus system ignores the grid row if it already exists in the list box

So far so good and it is working perfectly!

Twist:
If there is onyl one control on the page - All is good
But if the control is multiple times on the web page - it is not working as desired

The error is 'coz same java script getting copied for each user control so only the last one is working

Below is the code ... help!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function list_DblClick(s, e) {
        s.RemoveItem(s.GetSelectedIndex())
    }


    function grid_DblClick(s, e) {
        var sfn = s.GetColumn(0).fieldName + ';' + s.GetColumn(1).fieldName
        s.GetRowValues(s.GetFocusedRowIndex(), sfn, OnGetRowValues);
    }

    //check for duplicate and add new
    function OnGetRowValues(values) {
        var sFound = "False"
        for (var i = 0; i < selList.GetItemCount(); i++) {
            if (values[0] == selList.GetItem(i).value) {
                sFound = "True"
            }
        };
        if (sFound == "False") {
            selList.AddItem(values[1], values[0])
        };
    }
</script>


<br />
<br />
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdSelection" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" Width="100%">
        <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="grid_DblClick" />
        <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="True" />
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
<br />
<br />
    <dx:ASPxListBox ID="listSelected" ClientInstanceName="selList" runat="server" Height="250px" Width="100%" >
     <ClientSideEvents ItemDoubleClick="list_DblClick" />
    </dx:ASPxListBox>
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try using Firebug or Developer Tools and see if there is any error in the browser's console.

Comment: Hello Tony, thanks for the responding, there is no error as such but the javascript is getting created for each instance of the user control, causing duplicate functions, function "OnGetRowValue" references "selList" for checking the duplicates, now only the last user control is getting used! What I need is A generic function which can be called from any user control with we passing the controls and do the same as current OnGetRowValue function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using a user control, try loading the JavaScript code in the code-behind using Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock (via a key) and check if that JS has already been loaded using  [IsClientScriptBlockRegistered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isclientscriptblockregistered%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Doing it this way is much more efficient and should work since you're only declaring a function a single time as oppose to n-number of times (which is probably why it's throwing an error on the client-side).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.71).aspx